# Check if object is iterable

Tags: javascript

```
const [, segment1, segment2] = "string".match(/([^/]+)\/(.*)/);
```

returns object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

```
const [, segment1, segment2] = "name/lastname".match(/([^/]+)\/(.*)/);
console.log(segment1, segment2)
```

how can I check if is iterable? or check if segment1 and segment2 both are not null/undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `match` to a variable, so you can test if the match succeeded before trying to use the capture groups.

```
const match = "string".match(/([^/]+)\/(.*)/);
if (match) {
    const [, segment1, segment2] = match;
    console.log(segment1, segment2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`astring.match(/re(g)e(x)/)` returns `null` if the string does not match the regex. And you cannot deconstruct `null`, neither as object nor as array.

So you can do the following

```
let [,a,b] = (astring.match(/re(g)e(x)/) || []);
```

Ie, if the `match` returns `null` return a default array which you can deconstruct. Then `a` and `b` will both be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this:

```
const [fullMatch, segment1, segment2] = "string".match(/([^/]+)\/(.*)/)??[null];
if(fullMatch!==null) {
  console.log(segment1, segment2)
}
```

If `match` does not find anything it returns `null` if that’s the case you can utilize the `??` operator and use `[null]` as the result of the expression.

That way `fullMatch` will be a string in case of a match or `null` if no match happened.

But I still would suggest the answer of [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68536427/1960455) because there the  `segment1` and `segment2` exists only in the if block.

The code I showed would actually only make sense if you use `let` instead of `const` and when you want assign those two variables with some fallback values in the case when no match was found.